# XMLSerializer: Deserializing as derived type

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I've got my fingers crossed that someone out there has a good understanding of the Microsoft XmlSerializer.

Basically, I have built a system for outputting XML on the back of the serializer which is now causing me a lot of hassle and I am trying to avoid a significant re-write.

### Introduction

My current system employs a lot of derived classes.

For example,

BaseResponse -> CarParkResponse -> CarParkResponseInherited

BaseResponse and CarParkResponse (both in a library dll) are seperate from CarParkResponseInherited.

As a result, the base classes are ignorent of the derived class.

### What I have done

-> Declared derived classes

I appreciate that in order for xmlserializer to do its thing, there are a number of ways to declare dervied classes.

- Declare derived classes in base classes using XmlInclude

or

- Declared types to be serialised and deserialised in xmlSerialiser. For example:

> > XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CarParkResponse), new Type[] { typeof(CarParkParameters), typeof(CarParkInformation) });

I have gone with the latter.

### What I am trying to do

Because the derived classes are seperate and they share the same properties, what I am trying to do is serialize the dervied class as the subclass.

In other words deserialize CarParkResponseInherited as a CarParkResponse.

In "CarParkResponseInherited" I am using the declaration XmlTypeAttribute("CarParkResponse").

Initially this causes a problem when serialized

> > Types 'CarParkResponseInherited' and 'CarParkResponse' both use the XML type name, 'CarParkResponse', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type."

as the type is already in use "CarParkResponse" so I've declased XmlType("Response") in "CarParkResponse" to get around this.

### The Problem

I am now trying to Deserialize the XML returned but I'm now getting the following problem.

> > The specified type was not recognized: name='CarParkResponse', namespace='', at OriginalRequest xmlns=''

Frustratingly the CarParkResponse is there. I am wondering if this is down to the fact I've used XmlType("Response") in the class and the serializer doesn't recognise the class as being type of CarParkResponse

### So my question is

Basically is it possible to pass a derived class as a sub class and have it deserialized as the subclass using the XmlSerializer?

I have experimented with the xml produced.

For example, if I don't use the Serialization tags (such as XmlType() etc.) anywhere in my code. The xml produced will produce a carparkresponse element with "type" as an attribute.

The value is "CarParkResponseInherited". I have written some code that removes "Inherited" from the value which does allow it to be deserialized.

This approach is obviously not good so I am hoping there is a good way around this.

### So...

if there is anyone out there that has had to patience to read through this post and can help or offer advice it would be most appreciated as I am all out of ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do something using the XmlAttributeOverrides class.  It's mostly used for specific property overrides, so it may or may not be the best thing for you.

The long way around would be to go ahead and serialize as the inherited class.  Then, if the mappings are the same, deserialize the xml into the base class, and then, re-serialize into what you want.

Depending on how much or how little control you have over the assemblies, you could override the serialization on the inherited class so it does it as the base class.

Comment: Cheers for that response, I had a mess around with XmlAttributeOverrides, it moved me a step further then I hit some other issues with the data inside my response object (one of them was a List). I've had to side step the XmlSerializer for the time being. I intend to revisit the problem when I've got some time and post it here. I am using inheritence quite heavily and I think it is this that is causing the XmlSerializer a problem.